# How to find out xorg version? or "what's my xorg version?"

Tags: version, xorg

ATI docs says i need:

> XOrg 6.9, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5 or 7.6

`Xorg -version` says:

```
X.Org X Server 1.11.1.902(1.11.2 RC 2)
[...]
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[...]
xorg-server 2:1.11.1.902-1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bit confusing, because the official [documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/changelog.html) refers to the latest versions as `X11R7.6` and `XServer 1.9`. Based on these numbers, you are running "X.Org 7.6" as your X.Org Server is at version `1.11.`**`1.9`**`02`.

Comment: ok, not as simple! just found out the hard way that ATI's catalyst drivers are NOT compatible with X11, even if it's technically "7.6"

Answer (score 15):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I used:

```
sudo X -version
```

Comment: Something wrong with that? Why did I get a -1?

Comment: No idea who downvoted you, but this seems the simplest answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can take a look at the version reported in your packaging system, in Debian:

```
$ apt-cache show xserver-xorg | grep Version
Version: 1:7.5+8
```

In this example the version should be **7.5**.

Comment: in debian testing it's `2:1.11.something`... i just wiped it out and am installing -stable. if i have any lucky with radeon card i will not miss much the awesomeness in -test.

Comment: I'd rather use `dpkg -p xserver-xorg` which shows what actually installed instead of the querying the remote.

Comment: This gives me version of an old xserver, although i running a new one. I posted in a new answer how I got it on a up to date Ubuntu system

Comment: In my ubuntu `22.04` the above shows: `1:7.7+23ubuntu2` while `sudo X -version`  and `head /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep xorg-server` show `2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2.5`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: 7.6.

X is split up into separate repositories for each component since X11R7.0. 
The releases is a bunch of module versions known to work together and combined into one set. Individual components changes much more often.

The latest XOrg release, [X11R7.6](http://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/7.6), included xorg-server 1.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

One way is looking at the log file to which the version is printed when the server starts:

```
head /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep xorg-server
```

Comment: This has the benefit of also showing you display driver details etc, which is also handy in debugging issues.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a few options:
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221802/how-to-check-your-current-xorg-version

Ubuntu: `dpkg -l |grep xserver-xorg-core`

RHEL/CentOS : `rpm -qa |grep xorg-x11-server-Xorg`

SUSE: `rpm -qa |grep xorg-x11-server`

The Ubuntu command worked for me.
But the answer provided by @user1383029 seems to be the simplest and clearest.